# Intel® WiFi Link 5100 - no wireless networks found - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, network-manager, intel, intel-wireless, wicd

I have a random computer called a Seneca Data Carbon 14.  Made by a small NY company.
I loaded 12.04 LTS on it and I can't get wireless. Ehternet works fine.

The adapter is the **Intel® WiFi Link 5100.**

I have a feeling the Wireless Radio is off but the FN+F2 Radio switch does nothing and the button that looks like a radio switch next to volume also does nothing. Wireless LED is off.

I tried installing WICD and uninstalling network-manager. no luck.  Now I have both installed.

I tried downloading the iwlagn driver and installing per Chili555's instruction but I'm not sure it worked because as you can see below, iwlwifi seems prevalent. Also, I got no indication that the iwlwifi was removed.  I am running out of ideas and about to just go back to windows as a non wifi Laptop is not that great.

I also created a file in

Here are a few results:

```
carbon@carbon-pro:~$ rfkill list all
0: cmpc_rfkill: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


carbon@carbon-pro:~$ sudo modprobe iwlagn
[sudo] password for carbon: 
carbon@carbon-pro:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   23.137796] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[   23.137806] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   23.137830] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: pci_resource_len = 0x00002000
[   23.137833] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: pci_resource_base = ffffc9000035c000
[   23.137836] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: HW Revision ID = 0x0
[   23.138016] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[   23.138066] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN, REV=0x54
[   23.138232] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   23.160065] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x11f, CALIB=0x4
[   23.160070] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Device SKU: 0Xf0
[   23.160097] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 24 802.11a channels
[   23.395299] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 8.83.5.1 build 33692
[   23.400039] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   23.898631] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   23.901656] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   23.937458] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Hardware error detected.  Restarting.
[   23.937464] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 8.83.5.1 build 33692
[   23.937536] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   23.937538] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00040220, count: -1222849788
[   23.937542] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x9D93948F | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   23.937545] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x74BC6C25 | uPc
[   23.937547] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD4D8EAF7 | branchlink1
[   23.937550] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x79F929A3 | branchlink2
[   23.937552] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x25185FAF | interruptlink1
[   23.937555] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x7367EF6F | interruptlink2
[   23.937557] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x7686C34C | data1
[   23.937559] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x6F06C975 | data2
[   23.937562] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xFBAF3ACB | line
[   23.937564] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xF7C9DD06 | beacon time
[   23.937566] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x7D93D56F | tsf low
[   23.937569] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4C3ED509 | tsf hi
[   23.937571] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xFD0DAAFE | time gp1
[   23.937573] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x6EEFE341 | time gp2
[   23.937576] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x66FF4FF5 | time gp3
[   23.937578] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x28E5C81E | uCode version
[   23.937580] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x97F79493 | hw version
[   23.937583] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4FFFDB4F | board version
[   23.937585] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x6530D9E0 | hcmd
[   23.937588] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: CSR values:
[   23.937590] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: (2nd byte of CSR_INT_COALESCING is CSR_INT_PERIODIC_REG)
[   23.937596] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        CSR_HW_IF_CONFIG_REG: 0X00480303
[   23.937601] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:          CSR_INT_COALESCING: 0X00000040
[   23.937606] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                     CSR_INT: 0X20000000
[   23.937611] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                CSR_INT_MASK: 0X00000000
[   23.937617] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_FH_INT_STATUS: 0X00000000
[   23.937622] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 CSR_GPIO_IN: 0X00000000
[   23.937627] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                   CSR_RESET: 0X00000009
[   23.937632] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                CSR_GP_CNTRL: 0X080003c5
[   23.937637] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                  CSR_HW_REV: 0X00000054
[   23.937642] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:              CSR_EEPROM_REG: 0X00000000
[   23.937647] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:               CSR_EEPROM_GP: 0X90000004
[   23.937652] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:              CSR_OTP_GP_REG: 0X00060000
[   23.937658] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 CSR_GIO_REG: 0X00080044
[   23.937663] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:            CSR_GP_UCODE_REG: 0X00000000
[   23.937668] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_GP_DRIVER_REG: 0X00000000
[   23.937673] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP1: 0X00000000
[   23.937678] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP2: 0X00000000
[   23.937683] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 CSR_LED_REG: 0X00000018
[   23.937688] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        CSR_DRAM_INT_TBL_REG: 0X00000000
[   23.937694] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        CSR_GIO_CHICKEN_BITS: 0X27800200
[   23.937699] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:             CSR_ANA_PLL_CFG: 0X00880300
[   23.937704] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_HW_REV_WA_REG: 0X0001001a
[   23.937709] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        CSR_DBG_HPET_MEM_REG: 0Xffff0000
[   23.937712] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: FH register values:
[   23.937726] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:         FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_STTS_WPTR_REG: 0X06607400
[   23.937739] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_RBDCB_BASE_REG: 0X006626b0
[   23.937752] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                  FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_WPTR: 0X000000f8
[   23.937765] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:         FH_MEM_RCSR_CHNL0_CONFIG_REG: 0X80819104
[   23.937778] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:          FH_MEM_RSSR_SHARED_CTRL_REG: 0X0000003c
[   23.937791] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:            FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_STATUS_REG: 0X07030000
[   23.937805] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:    FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_ENABLE_ERR_IRQ2DRV: 0X00000000
[   23.937819] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                FH_TSSR_TX_STATUS_REG: 0X05ff0000
[   23.937833] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 FH_TSSR_TX_ERROR_REG: 0X00000000
[   23.937882] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Log capacity 118980931 is bogus, limit to 256 entries
[   23.937885] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Log write index -479274738 is bogus, limit to 256
[   23.937888] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Event Log Dump: display last 20 entries
[   23.937906] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0570291876:0xcf42790d:3081624423
[   23.937917] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:2080102228:0x510cdfeb:3867114880
[   23.937928] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:1204167583:0xd3a9b49f:3757509231
[   23.937939] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3598207773:0xad5cf0ae:601834879
[   23.937951] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3616630249:0xe7e9be8d:1596430253
[   23.937962] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:4175233537:0xd5da39b3:970899957
[   23.937974] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:2712366750:0x153f51e7:2721607275
[   23.937985] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0718138711:0x3cdffdbf:1641189246
[   23.937995] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3712401141:0xbf759b0c:602864538
[   23.938007] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3884957690:0x1fdcff2f:3120168423
[   23.938018] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3667864789:0x9c29b57d:2389098332
[   23.938029] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3692789065:0xb7fb175f:2138878854
[   23.938040] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:4233080783:0xdba22fae:3672233812
[   23.938051] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0431416889:0x8bf6f7f5:1811855613
[   23.938062] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:1801449446:0x2a7798ad:4025966542
[   23.938074] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:1850948857:0x7b21c75f:2990459829
[   23.938084] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3841960874:0xf4dcb9bc:182299815
[   23.938095] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:4290679089:0xef2d9b57:3602627871
[   23.938105] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3388896124:0x267f4374:3117114591
[   23.938116] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:1093868139:0x2ed05ba1:4279663190
[   28.900054] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the INST uCode section
[   28.900299] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   28.900341] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[   28.901740] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   28.904736] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   28.941191] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Hardware error detected.  Restarting.
[   28.941197] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 8.83.5.1 build 33692
[   28.941268] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   28.941270] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00040220, count: -1222849788
[   28.941274] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x9D93948F | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[   28.941277] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x74BC6C25 | uPc
[   28.941279] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xD4D8EAF7 | branchlink1
[   28.941282] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x79F929A3 | branchlink2
[   28.941284] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x25185FAF | interruptlink1
[   28.941286] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x7367EF6F | interruptlink2
[   28.941289] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x7686C34C | data1
[   28.941291] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x6F06C975 | data2
[   28.941293] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xFBAF3ACB | line
[   28.941296] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xF7C9DD06 | beacon time
[   28.941298] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x7D93D56F | tsf low
[   28.941301] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4C3ED509 | tsf hi
[   28.941303] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xFD0DAAFE | time gp1
[   28.941305] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x6EEFE341 | time gp2
[   28.941308] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x66FF4FF5 | time gp3
[   28.941310] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x28E5C81E | uCode version
[   28.941312] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x97F79493 | hw version
[   28.941315] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4FFFDB4F | board version
[   28.941317] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x6530D9E0 | hcmd
[   28.941320] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: CSR values:
[   28.941322] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: (2nd byte of CSR_INT_COALESCING is CSR_INT_PERIODIC_REG)
[   28.941327] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        CSR_HW_IF_CONFIG_REG: 0X00480303
[   28.941333] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:          CSR_INT_COALESCING: 0X00000040
[   28.941338] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                     CSR_INT: 0X20000000
[   28.941343] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                CSR_INT_MASK: 0X00000000
[   28.941348] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_FH_INT_STATUS: 0X00000000
[   28.941353] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 CSR_GPIO_IN: 0X00000000
[   28.941358] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                   CSR_RESET: 0X00000009
[   28.941363] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                CSR_GP_CNTRL: 0X080003c5
[   28.941368] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                  CSR_HW_REV: 0X00000054
[   28.941373] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:              CSR_EEPROM_REG: 0X00000000
[   28.941378] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:               CSR_EEPROM_GP: 0X90000004
[   28.941384] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:              CSR_OTP_GP_REG: 0X00060000
[   28.941389] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 CSR_GIO_REG: 0X00080044
[   28.941394] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:            CSR_GP_UCODE_REG: 0X00000000
[   28.941399] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_GP_DRIVER_REG: 0X00000000
[   28.941404] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP1: 0X00000000
[   28.941409] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_UCODE_DRV_GP2: 0X00000000
[   28.941415] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 CSR_LED_REG: 0X00000018
[   28.941420] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        CSR_DRAM_INT_TBL_REG: 0X00000000
[   28.941425] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        CSR_GIO_CHICKEN_BITS: 0X27800200
[   28.941430] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:             CSR_ANA_PLL_CFG: 0X00000000
[   28.941435] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:           CSR_HW_REV_WA_REG: 0X0001001a
[   28.941440] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        CSR_DBG_HPET_MEM_REG: 0Xffff0000
[   28.941443] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: FH register values:
[   28.941456] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:         FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_STTS_WPTR_REG: 0X06607400
[   28.941469] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:        FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_RBDCB_BASE_REG: 0X006626b0
[   28.941482] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                  FH_RSCSR_CHNL0_WPTR: 0X000000f8
[   28.941495] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:         FH_MEM_RCSR_CHNL0_CONFIG_REG: 0X80819104
[   28.941508] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:          FH_MEM_RSSR_SHARED_CTRL_REG: 0X0000003c
[   28.941521] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:            FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_STATUS_REG: 0X07030000
[   28.941534] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:    FH_MEM_RSSR_RX_ENABLE_ERR_IRQ2DRV: 0X00000000
[   28.941546] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                FH_TSSR_TX_STATUS_REG: 0X05ff0000
[   28.941559] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0:                 FH_TSSR_TX_ERROR_REG: 0X00000000
[   28.941609] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Log capacity 118980931 is bogus, limit to 256 entries
[   28.941612] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Log write index -479274738 is bogus, limit to 256
[   28.941614] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Event Log Dump: display last 20 entries
[   28.941632] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0570291876:0xcf42790d:3081624423
[   28.941643] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:2080102228:0x510cdfeb:3867114880
[   28.941653] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:1204167583:0xd3a9b49f:3757509231
[   28.941664] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3598207773:0xad5cf0ae:601834879
[   28.941674] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3616630249:0xe7e9be8d:1596430253
[   28.941685] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:4175233537:0xd5da39b3:970899957
[   28.941695] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:2712366750:0x153f51e7:2721607275
[   28.941705] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0718138711:0x3cdffdbf:1641189246
[   28.941716] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3712401141:0xbf759b0c:602864538
[   28.941726] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3884957690:0x1fdcff2f:3120168423
[   28.941736] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3667864789:0x9c29b57d:2389098332
[   28.941747] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3692789065:0xb7fb175f:2138878854
[   28.941757] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:4233080783:0xdba22fae:3672233812
[   28.941768] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:0431416889:0x8bf6f7f5:1811855613
[   28.941778] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:1801449446:0x2a7798ad:4025966542
[   28.941788] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:1850948857:0x7b21c75f:2990459829
[   28.941799] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3841960874:0xf4dcb9bc:182299815
[   28.941809] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:4290679089:0xef2d9b57:3602627871
[   28.941820] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:3388896124:0x267f4374:3117114591
[   28.941830] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: EVT_LOGT:1093868139:0x2ed05ba1:4279663190
[   33.904118] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the INST uCode section
[   33.904470] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
[   33.904489] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   33.904528] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[   33.911541] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   33.914547] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   38.916152] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the INST uCode section
[   38.916505] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
[   38.916529] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   38.916570] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[   38.916874] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   38.919824] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   43.920062] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the INST uCode section
[   43.920417] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
[   43.920437] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   43.920476] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[   44.092216] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   44.095158] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   49.092115] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the INST uCode section
[   49.092468] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
[   49.092487] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   49.092529] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[   49.107129] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   49.110113] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   54.108112] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the INST uCode section
[   54.108465] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
[   54.108485] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[   54.108524] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[   96.874102] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[   96.877101] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[  101.876061] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the INST uCode section
[  101.876411] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
[  101.876431] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[  101.876468] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
[  102.986344] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
[  102.989317] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[  107.988209] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Could not load the INST uCode section
[  107.988591] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Master Disable Timed Out, 100 usec
[  107.988618] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
[  107.988672] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
carbon@carbon-pro:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your network settings and select wireless and choose the network name as your wifi network and click connect. It worked for me.